# @EmbebedId in Generics class

Tags: hibernate, generics, composite-primary-key

I create an class MyCompositeKey with Generics:

```
class MyCompositeKey<T> {
    T compositeId0;
    Integer compositeId1;
    Integer compositeId2;
}
```

So I can use it in many tables that have the same composite key, varying only the type:

```
class Table1<Integer> {
    @EmbebedId
    MyCompositeKey<Integer> compositeId;
    //other attributes
}
class Table2<String> {
    @EmbebedId
    MyCompositeKey<String> compositeId;
    //other attributes
}
//...
```

The problem is if I use my class:

```
class MyId {
    Integer id0;
    Integer id1;
}
class Table3<MyId> {
    @EmbebedId
    MyCompositeKey<MyId> compositeId;
    //other attributes
}
```

Hibernate tries to find column "compositeId0" in Table3, that doesnt exist (my table 3 has composite key: id0, id1,compositeId1,compositeId2). How can I do this?

PS: If I put @EmbeddedId in "MyCompositeKey.compositeId0" works for my class, but doesnt work for Integer, Long, String... Because Hibernate tries to find column "value".